# Color overlay on specific area of UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to overlay a color on a UIImage, but only on the left half of the image (I'm using code from http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage to overlay the color). The code I have now is:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color{

// begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.line.image.size.width/2, self.line.image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

// get a reference to that context we created
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// set the fill color
[color setFill];

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// set the blend mode to overlay, and the original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.line.image.CGImage);

// set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (overlay) a colored rectangle
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.line.image.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

// generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//return the color-burned image
return coloredImg;
}
```

I thought setting the size to be half the width would work, but everything still gets color. I guess I'm missing something very fundamental. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
```

you are adding a rectangle with the full size.

Comment: The rect should be using the the size.width I defined above, right?

Comment: I suppose so - is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, the size was made with a width of (size of image)/2. And the rect was made with that size.width. But the entire image is still be overlayed with the color.

Comment: Exactly. You are using rect instead of size.

Comment: I defined the rect to have a size that is made with a width of (size of image)/2